# OS Catalina save as right arrow shortcut puts cursor at the end of extension, not the filename

Tags: finder, catalina

Since updating to Catalina, specifically in Adobe apps, when performing a save as, the right arrow shortcut, which used to send the cursor to the end of the filename, now very annoyingly, puts it at the end of the extension. Anyone else had this issue, and more importanly, anyone know how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try alt arrow to the right, I should stop before the period.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately this doesn't work either.